# Obtain the OTP sent to to mobile number

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

In Firebase Auth, while signing in the user through the phone number, I can initiate the verification process through `verifyPhoneNumber` but can't get the OTP sent to the phone number.

The other way to obtain the code is, to read the device's messages, which is not an ideal practice as the requirement of the OTP is just for internal purposes only.

Below is the code of my `AuthController`

Tough to understand the vote of the reviewers in favour of closing the question.

```
Future<void> verifyUserWithMobile({required String mobileNo}) async {
  try {
    bool connected = await _utils.checkInternetConnectivity();
    if (!connected) {
      throw ("No internet connection found");
    } else {
      await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: mobileNo,
        verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential) {},
        verificationFailed: (error) {
          throw (error);
        },
        codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) {
          otpSentStatus.value = Status.success;
          verificationCode.value = verificationId;
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {},
      );
    }
  } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
    debugPrint("OTP Send Error: $error");
    if (error.message != null) {
      //...
    }
  } catch (error) {
    debugPrint("Error: $error");
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: if you wont post the code, please check the documentation https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/ for phone auth